# Creating a shader language

Tags: programming-languages, shader

Is it at all possible for an individual to create a shader programming language?

Comment: Why not? Just compile your language into GLSL or whatever else.

Comment: well how about 'creating' another GLSL, if you know what I mean

Comment: First of all, do you know how to write shaders in a general purpose language? Because before you can create your language from the ground up, you need to know about the problem domain, and how to implement the underlying features.

Comment: @Ishihara, no, I do not understand. You must be a committee built of fat cats to be able to push a new standard and force all the major vendors to provide drivers with its support. And yet it will take a decade or more for a standard to be adopted by everyone. But, if you're asking about implementing a shader language for any given specific platform (AMD, NVidia, whatever) - yes, you can easily do it, just hack the existing open source drivers (or compile to PTX if your platform is NVidia).

Answer (score 2):

SK-logic has the answer right there as the first comment. You can build a custom shading language compiler which takes the custom language and "compiles" it into GLSL language, or HLSL or anything else.

This is a realistic question because existing shader methodologies can create combinatorial explosions of shaders and can make your shader implementation become very restricted and interdependent. A custom shader language can make it easy for those dependencies to be automated, for example, for multiple layers of effects, or level-of-detail control.

You can make the shaders work they way you "wish" they worked. It also adds a perfect portability layer completely abstracting the underlying shader language if desired.

The generated shaders will go to the driver which takes it the rest of the way and compiles native code for the GPU.

It is fairly straightforward to make a compiler. All you need is a (lexer and) parser, build an abstract syntax tree from it, then do a few passes over the tree to gather information you need to know up front and do some simple constant expresssion optimizations, and generate the shaders as output from the syntax tree. I'm using lemon as parser generator lately.